# Given measurements from a event series as input, how do I generate an infinite input series with the same profile?

Tags: statistics, scheduling, simulation, montecarlo, markov-chains

I'm currently working with a system that makes scheduling decisions based on a series of requests and the state of the system.

I would like to take the stream of real inputs, mock out some of the components, and run simulations against the rest.  The idea is to use it for planning with respect to system capacity (i.e. when to scale certain components), tracking down certain failure modes, and analyzing the effects of changes to the codebase (i.e. simulations with version A compared to simulations with version B).

I can do everything related to this, except generate a suitable input stream.  Replaying the exact input from production hasn't been very helpful because it's hard to get a long enough data stream to tease out some of the behavior that I'm trying to find.  In other words, if production falls over at 300 days of input, I don't have enough data to find out until after it fell over.  Repeating the same input set has been considered; but after a few initial tries, the developers all agree that the simulation seems to "need more random".

About this particular system:

- The input is a series of irregularly spaced events (i.e. a stochastic process with discrete time and continuous state space).
- Properties are not [independent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistically_independent) of each other.
- Even the more independent of the properties are composites of other properties that will always be, by nature, invisible to me (leading to a [multi-modal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimodal_distribution)).
- Request interval is not independent of other properties (i.e. lots of requests for small amounts of resources come through in a batch, large requests don't).
- There are feedback loops in it.
- It's provably chaotic.

So:

> Given a stream of input events with a certain distribution of various properties (including interval), how do I generate an infinite stream of events with the same distribution across a number of non-independent properties?

Having looked around, I think I need to do a Markov-Chain Monte-Carlo Simulation.  My problem is figuring out how to build the Markov-Chain from the existing input data.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is possible to model the input with a [Copula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_%28probability_theory%29). There are tools that help you doing so, e.g. see [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.4108/ICST.SIMUTOOLS2009.5596). Apart from this, I would suggest to move the question to http://stats.stackexchange.com, as this is a *statistical* problem and will likely draw more attention over there.